# convert array into associate array and indexed array

Tags: php

I have an array

```
Array ( [0] => 4-8-2019 [1] => 5-8-2019 [2] => 5 [3] => 6 ,[4]=>1,[5]=>2 )
```

How I can make this.Pleasse help me I have tried array mege but not working

```
Array ( [0] =>
[0]=> 4-8-2019 
[1] => 5 
[2] => 1 

[1] =>[0]=> 5-8-2019
      [1]=>6
      [2]=>2 )
```

Comment: What is the logic behind the conversion?

Comment: Can you show the code you currently use to create the output array.

Answer (score 0):

You want to seperate you array into two by every other item.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $result[$key & 1][] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only logic I found in your example is about even and odd indexes. If that's what you want to do, try this :

```
<?php

$array = [
    '4-8-2019',
    '5-8-2019',
    '5',
    '6',
    '1',
    '2',
];

$odds = [];
$evens = [];

foreach ($array as $index => $value) {
    if ($index % 2 === 0) {
        $evens[] = $value;
    } else {
        $odds[] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump([$evens, $odds]);
```

Which outputs :

```
 array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "4-8-2019"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "5"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "5-8-2019"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "6"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```